# Kernel functions not recognized by compiler

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to compile an example of the CUDA Toolkit (Asian Option by MC). I'm using Qt. I copied a pro file adapted to CUDA that I found on the Internet, but every time I have a kernel function `foo<<<x,y>>>(...)` in my code, this last one is underlined with red colour. And unsurprisingly, when I try to compile it, it fails.

Do you have any idea where it could come from?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you run GCC to compile it, while you need to use nvcc which first of all does preprocessing - `kernel<<<>>>` stuff expansion and generates code for GPU.

Comment: Hi Adrian,                                                         Thank you for your answer. One dummy question: How can I run nvcc with Qt?

Comment: Have a try setting it in QT Creator Settings. Settings/Building and running/Compilers.

Comment: I see what you mean last time. Actually, I was using MinGW. So I found what you were talking about. But when I click on custom they ask me for: 1) Name 2) Compiler Path, 3) Make path, 4) ABI, 5) Predefined macros, 6) Header paths, 7) C++11 flags, 8) Qt mkspecs.